# Property of exact sequences?

Tags: ring-theory

If I have a commutative ring $R$ and an exact sequence

$0\to M'\to M\to M''\to 0$  where $\epsilon:M'\to M$ and $\sigma:M\to M''$

do I get an exact sequence

$0\to M'\to M\to M''\to 0$ by means of $\epsilon \circ id:M'\times N\to M\times N$ and $\sigma\circ id:M\times N\to M''\times N$?

By $f\circ g$ I mean the mapping $(x,y)$ to $(f(x),g(y))$  (not sure how to do the tensor product symbol).

The reason I ask is that my notes are a scrambled scrawling of material I cannot make sense of.  And It looks like I have a lemma without a conclusion here but this is what I Guess it is.  Can anyone confirm?  Thanks so much.

Comment: The tensor is product symbol is `\otimes`. Are you taking that, or the direct product?

Comment: in my notes it says $\otimes_R$ maybe that means direct?

Comment: oh i just read further, and my notes go on to say that if the resulting sequence is guaranteed to be exact, then the $R$-module $N$ is said to be flat.  but he refers to the resulting sequence as "tensored" so the $\otimes_{R}$ must denote tensor product after all

does this sound correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not, in general, true. Modules $N$ for which the resulting sequence is always exact were given the adjective [flat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module) by Serre, and this property has interesting geometric implications. The standard counterexample is tensoring the injection
\[
0 \to \mathbf Z \stackrel{\times 2}{\longrightarrow} \mathbf Z
\]
with $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$. However, tensoring *is* [right exact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_functor#Formal_definitions), i.e.
\[
M' \otimes N \to M \otimes N \to M'' \otimes N \to 0
\]
must be an exact sequence.

Comment: Of course Dylan is correct, but in fact, right exactness gives us the more general statement that $M\to N\to L\to0$ gets mapped to exact sequences under $\bullet\otimes_R A$. If tensor was exact, the tor functors wouldn't be very interesting.

Comment: @AlexYoucis That's a good point. I think the two notions of right exactness are equivalent, but that isn't obvious (at least to me). I'll try to work out the diagram later on. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 2):

[I assume that you are interested in the direct product as you wrote.]

The sequence you constructed will not be exact because the composition of $\epsilon\times\mathrm{id}$ and $\sigma\times\mathrm{id}$ is $0\times\mathrm{id}$, which is not the zero map.